# Getting following issue while run kotlin multiplatform code in Xcode

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

> Task :shared:compileKotlinIosX64 UP-TO-DATE > Task
> :shared:linkDebugFrameworkIosX64 FAILED e: Compilation failed: Backend
> Internal error: Exception during IR lowering File being compiled:
> /opt/buildAgent/work/b2fef8360e1bcf3d/formats/json/commonMain/src/kotlinx/serialization/json/JsonAnnotations.kt
> The root cause java.lang.AssertionError was thrown at:
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.lower.InitializersLowering$InitializersTransformer.lowerConstructors(InitializersLowering.kt:161)
> * Source files: * Compiler version info: Konan: 1.6.10 / Kotlin:
> 1.6.10 * Output kind: STATIC_CACHE e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal
> error: Exception during IR lowering File being compiled:
> /opt/buildAgent/work/b2fef8360e1bcf3d/formats/json/commonMain/src/kotlinx/serialization/json/JsonAnnotations.kt
> The root cause java.lang.AssertionError was thrown at:
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.lower.InitializersLowering$InitializersTransformer.lowerConstructors(InitializersLowering.kt:161)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException(CodegenUtil.kt:239)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException$default(CodegenUtil.kt:235)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invokeSequential(performByIrFile.kt:68)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(performByIrFile.kt:55)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(performByIrFile.kt:41)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.ToplevelPhasesKt$dependenciesLowerPhase$1.invoke(ToplevelPhases.kt:290)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.ToplevelPhasesKt$dependenciesLowerPhase$1.invoke(ToplevelPhases.kt:276)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:22)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:43)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanDriverKt.runTopLevelPhases(KonanDriver.kt:34)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native.doExecute(K2Native.kt:81) at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native.doExecute(K2Native.kt:37) at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:92)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98) at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:76) at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:45) at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:227)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion$mainNoExitWithGradleRenderer$1.invoke(K2Native.kt:393)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion$mainNoExitWithGradleRenderer$1.invoke(K2Native.kt:392)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.UtilKt.profileIf(Util.kt:22) at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.UtilKt.profile(Util.kt:16) at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion.mainNoExitWithGradleRenderer(K2Native.kt:392)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2NativeKt.mainNoExitWithGradleRenderer(K2Native.kt:634)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt$daemonMain$1.inv

Comment: It's going to be quite difficult to provide any help for this error without seeing some more of your code and configuration. I can see references to Kotlinx Serialization and Konan (Kotlin Native plugin), but I'm not sure what to suggest without more context. Could you please include your build.gradle and the relevant code that you are trying to compile?